# Ubuntu - FTP file edit permission denied

Tags: linux, ftp, file-transfer, file-permissions, ubuntu-server

I have been trying to make an Unturned server for my friends, and I cannot edit ANY files in it.

**What I've Tried:**

- I can't delete or upload to the FTP server; when I try to change the file permissions, it denies it.
- I have changed the `write_enable=NO` to `write_enable=YES` in `/etc/vsftpd.conf` but it didn't help. I cannot edit the permissions from the FTP server.
- Researching the web for answers, but I cannot find anything on this anywhere on the internet.

**Other Details:**

- I am using FileZilla for FTP services.

**Goal:**

I want to make it so anyone that can see the folder can edit it, and not just the terminal user.

If anyone can help me that would be great.

Comment: Is the user you/your friends use to log into the FTP server granted permissions for FTP transmission, and the FTP share?

Comment: And how do I do that exactly? I'm totally new to this FTP stuff.

Comment: There are a few ways to do this, but the best way is to see what group a folder belongs to, and make sure that the users belong to that group.  You can use `ls -l` to list file/folder permissions in your current directory, which will show you the owner and group of the file/folder (in that order). 
 You'd then use `groups` to see what group the current (logged in) user belongs to.  If you do have multiple user accounts, use `su [username here]` to switch to each user.

Comment: Doesn't even work. I have used all the accounts and nothing will let me edit it. It's FTP. Not command line.

Comment: FTP is a protocol, which can be executed in a GUI, or terminal.  Just to be certain, you have physical access to this server, right?

Comment: I got it fixed. I had to change the owner of the files. It was in root and I couldn't login to root. Took me a while. This was yesterday that I figured this out.

Answer (score 2):

## **-Solution-**

Solving this took me some time but I finally figured it out. You must first, login to the account you want on FTP (On a local network you may leave the port blank). If you can access the files, you are fine. Next, open a terminal connection to the Ubuntu Server itself. Once you have done so, login to an account with **sudo** permissions. You must then change the owner of the file. I suggest giving the user ownership of ***Everything*** in order to ensure full access.
First, run `cd ~`to change the seclected folder, then`sudo chown -R [User's Username]:root /home/[username]`. That should change the owner of the folder to the specified user along with all the files inside the folder. If you want to change ownership of just a specific file, run `sudo chown [User's Username]:root [Directory (example: /home/user/folder/document.txt)]`

### -Flat out Instructions-

Login to the user (**Sudo permissions required**), run `cd~`, find the folder you want, and run `sudo chown -R [User's Username]:root /home/[username]`. Or for a specific file, `sudo chown [User's Username]:root [Directory (example: /home/user/folder/document.txt)]`